# React Testing Library not changing state and doesn't rerender when it is called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I have some react code which implements a library which I have to inevitably use. My code is used to alter the appearance of a dropdown function and also passing the dropdown from the library I have to use some props.

The library, however, takes an onChange and a preSelected option as a prop, however on the first render it would fire the onChange since it would initialise with a null selection and then pick the selected option if it was passed in.

So to prevent this I created a firstLoad state and on the first load it will not change the redux state as the selected value prop is already a default value in the redux state.
The code looks something like this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {StyledDropdown} from './styleDropdown';
import {Dropdown} from 'library';

export const ADropdown = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [firstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(true);

    return (
        <StyledDropdown>
           <Dropdown
              label=""
              choices={[
                  {value:'1', label:'1'},
                  {value:'2', label:'2'}      
              ]}
              selected={2}
              onChange={(selectedItem) => {
                 if(firstTime){
                    setFirstTime(false);
                 }else{
                    dispatch({type:'changeItem', payload: selectedItem});
                 };
              };
           />
        </StyledDropdown>
    );
};
```

So the issue is when I come to test this with RTL, I understand that RTL is meant to primarily test items in the DOM but I do in a way want to ensure that the dispatch is not firing on its first render but only on subsequent onChange events.

I have tried the following but can never get the mocked dispatch to be called

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
});

test('a test for dispatch', async() => {
    await act(async() => render(<ADropdown/>));
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'1'})));
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', {name:'2'})));

    //test to see if the button changes its selection
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'2'})).toBeInDocument();

    expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'});
    };
);
```

it will fail on `expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'})` as it was called 0 times

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
   useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
})

test('a test for dispatch', async() => {
    await act(async() => render(<ADropdown/>));
    waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('button', {name: '1'}));

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'1'})));
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', {name:'2'})));

    // i dont think this is needed? as it never failed on this?
    waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('button', {name: '2'}));

    //test to see if the button changes its selection
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'2'})).toBeInDocument();

    expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'});
    };
);
```

it will fail on `expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'})` as it was called 0 times

```
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
})

test('a test for dispatch', async() => {
    const {rerender} = await act(async() => render(<ADropdown/>));
    // I have tried inserting rerender here and below after the last fire event occurs
    rerender(<ADropdown/>);
    waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('button', {name: '1'}));

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'1'})));
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', {name:'2'})));

    // i dont think this is needed? as it never failed on this?
    waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('button', {name: '2'}));

    //test to see if the button changes its selection
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', {name:'2'})).toBeInDocument();

    expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'});
    };
);
```

it will fail on `expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledWith({type:'changeItem', payload: '2'})` as it was called 0 times

I have also tried `fireEvent.select` and `fireEvent.change` however I may have implemented it incorrectly?
I have tried placing a console log in the onchange but not in the if block, but it does not seem to be firing again when rerender is called or any other time.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to writing unit tests.